# Error to match with my REGEX

Tags: java, regex, string

May i have some help to get those string with Regex .. Here is my source code ..

help me !!!

```
String t="01-21 10:56:41.161 D/RILJ    ( 2785): [rild] [2058]< VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE {1, 271c, 0000058d, 16, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}";
String Exp= "(VOICE_REGISTRATION_STATE) .(\\d+), (\\w+), (\\w+), (\\d+),";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b"+Exp+"\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
```

// indicate all matches on the line

```
    if (m.find()) {

  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"band="+m.group(2),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Lac="+m.group(3),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"CID="+m.group(4),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Tech="+m.group(5),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is only with the  word boundary you added at the last. Just remove it. Because there isn't a word boundary exists between a comma (*which exists next to the number 16*) and a space. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Exp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

[Just play with adding a word boundary at the last in here.](https://regex101.com/r/zM3pD6/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro , but i have not undertood why i have to remove the last b , i thougth b was  just used to bound the expression , isn't it ?

Comment: ok, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` are called word characters. Anything not of these characters are called non-word characters. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character. `,` and space are both non-word charcaters, so there isn't word boundary exists these two. You could ask me why the first `\b` works. It's because there is a word boundary exists between space (non-word) and `V` (_in VOICE_REGISTRATION_)